# Deleting /tmp/ before systemd service

Tags: boot, systemd, tmp

When the power of my machine is cut off the system doesnt have time to delete /tmp/.

How can I make sure the tmp folder is cleared before a systemd service is run?

Comment: Sorry, do you want to run the something on shutdown or start up ?

Comment: @Adonist on start up since the power can be cut off so running something is impossible on shutdown ( i think).

Answer (score 1):

Create a script to clean the folder you want or to do whatever you need and put it in /usr/bin/ and then create a systemd service as:

```
[Unit]
Description=OLPC Configuration
DefaultDependencies=no
After=sysinit.target local-fs.target
Before=base.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/bin/yourscript.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=base.target
```

Comment: Will this be run before any other systemd script?

Comment: That's the idea.