# Can I delete contents of temporary folders in Lubuntu 16.04?

Tags: lubuntu, filesystem, cleanup, tmp

I expect that as in Windows, in Lubuntu or in other Ubuntu-based operating systems, many temporary files are created and stored in temporary folders, for example, `/tmp` and `/var/tmp`.

To free up the disc space, **can I delete the contents of these folders without bugging up the system?**

Are there also other locations that may contain trash I can safely delete to clean the system?

Comment: "many temporary files" Nope. Just a few.  "To free up the disc space, can I delete the contents of these folders without bugging up the system?" That assumes deleting would free up space and it does not. Well not for long that is We consider /tmp just that: temporary. A reboot should be enough to clean out /tmp/

Comment: "Are there also other locations that may contain trash I can safely delete to clean the system?" Another temporary thing: apt caches deb packages. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/285691/is-it-possible-to-clean-the-apt-cache-from-the-command-line

Comment: Quote "We consider /tmp just that: temporary. A reboot should be enough to clean out /tmp"  My /var/tmp folder has a size of 66MB both before and also after reboot. Can I delete these files? How? Ricky

Comment: see https://askubuntu.com/questions/380238/how-to-clean-tmp and more importantly https://askubuntu.com/questions/944589/deleting-tmp-before-systemd-service How do you expect 66Mb to make a dent in your used space? And is to be expected the 66Mb are not used due to you using the system? ie. might that 66Mb come back? Cuz that would make it futile.